# Restoring monitors.xml file

Tags: unity, resolution, bumblebee

I was following [@Alex's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180686/17345) about my other question.

My GPU is GeForce GT 540M.

I installed `bumblebee` and `bumblebee-nvidia` packages. And reboot, i get this error :

```
none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes: Trying modes for CRTC 310 CRTC 310: trying mode 640x480@73Hz with output at 1920x1080@51Hz (pass 0) CRTC 310: trying mode 640x480@73Hz with output at 1920x1080@51Hz (pass 1)
```

and resolution reduced to 640*480 px. After that i uninstall bumblebee,

`sudo apt-get remove bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

And then, i followed [this instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862969) for this error. They said, delete your `monitors.xml` file. And i delete it. But it's not restored. There are only 1024x768 and 640x480 . My original resolution was 1920x1080.

I tried `unity --reset` after this, i get *Compiz closed unexpected* error.

[image]
[image]

Tried to install latest NVIDIA drivers :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Still there isn't 1920x1080 on **Displays** screen.

I want to restore my monitors.xml file and solve my problem.

### UPDATE

I just reinstall my Compiz. Now i don't get COMPIZ error when `unity --reset`

Comment: Can you attach your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file somewhere?

Comment: @Lekensteyn , http://pastebin.ca/2198290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow your driver installation got screwed up which broke the nvidia kernel/Xorg driver combination:

```
[    20.437] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    20.463] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    21.054] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    21.054]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    21.054]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    21.088] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    21.088] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    21.088] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    21.088] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    21.088] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
```

Try purging the nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

If the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so` and/ or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so` still exist, remove them too.

If you have previously installed nvidia from nvidia.com, follow these [If you've installed the driver from nvidia.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969) instructions. Finally, reinstall the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Reboot and everything should be working again.

---

Your laptop has a Nvidia GT 540M card which is most often an Optimus chip. However, it [seems that your manufacturer has disabled the Intel iGPU](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Sony-Vaio-VPC-F22S1E-B-FHD-Notebook.58855.0.html) and thereby disabled Optimus. This was detected by Bumblebee and therefore it refused to start at all. However, since this is not checked at installation of `bumblebee` and the nvidia driver is disabled, your desktop resolution got screwed up because it falls back to the VESA driver. This situation can be remedied by removing `bumblebee`:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

As a note to other readers, for machines that do not have the iGPU disabled there might be a BIOS option controlling whether the Intel or Nvidia GPU should be used by default.

Comment: THank you. It's solve my problem ! I have done a lots of things for solve my problem. I hope i don't broke anything :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is coming here with Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, one easy way to recreate your `monitors.xml` file is to just go to System Settings -> Displays -> click Apply